# Python Eval make datetime module available

Tags: python, datetime, eval

I am looking for a way to make the functions of datetime available within an eval expression. This would be the minimal working code

```
import datetime
input_string = 'from_{today:%m-%d}_to_{yesterday:%m-%d}'
input_dict = {
        'today': eval('datetime.datetime.today()', {'datetime': datetime}, {}),
        'yesterday': eval('datetime.datetime.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=1)', {'datetime': datetime}, {})
        }
print(input_string.format(**input_dict))
```

However this does not prevent the eval function from executing method of `__builtins__`. How can I prevent it from accessing the `__builtins__`?

Comment: do you mean to put that # before `eval_dict = {format_key: eval(` or is it typo?

Comment: even if you make this work, an experienced user will almost certainly be able to break out of your sandbox and cause trouble. if this is for real (not a toy project) then you should probably write a proper parser instead of using `eval`

Comment: I think you just want a *function* that takes an input string, then computes the values of `today` and `yesterday` on demand to pass to the input string's `format` method. No `eval` necessary.

Comment: That is right. However the today and yersterday are just example datetimes. The user shall have the flexibility to access the whole datetime module, including calculations via timedelta.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bad idea. `eval` is all-or-nothing; it evaluates a valid Python expression, no matter what that expression contains. You can't limit it to the expression you *expect* a user to enter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do what I think you want to do:

```
import datetime
import math

user_input = input()

# set locals to a dict containing only datetime
# set globals to an empty dict  
eval(user_input, {'datetime': datetime}, dict())
```

If the user inputs "datetime.date.today()" then you get "datetime.date(2020, 2, 5)" out.  If the user inputs "math.acos(0.5)" then you get "NameError: name 'math' is not defined".

Note: As other people have said, I don't really endorse this approach for security reasons.  E.g. the user could input `'"datetime.date.today()" + quit()'` to quit your program or much, much worse.